# Covariance of non linear transformation of two variables

Tags: probability, statistics, finance, covariance

I am struggling to find a way to re write a covariance formula that includes non linear transformation of two variables. The formula is the following one:

$$\beta=\frac{\operatorname{cov}\left(r_A\cdot\frac{\mathrm{EUR}}{\mathrm{CHF}};r_I\cdot\frac{\mathrm{EUR}}{\mathrm{CHF}}\right)}{\operatorname{Var}\left(r_{I}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{EUR}}{\mathrm{CHF}}\right)}$$

I have to find a possible relation to the basic formula and the impact the transformation has:

$$\beta=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(r_A;r_I)}{\operatorname{Var}(r_{I})}$$

I tried to rewrite the covariance as expected value, but then I am stuck always with the non linear transformation.

Is there anyone who could give a hint or has any idea?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Would you please specify that transformation?  The transformation $A\mapsto \frac{\mathrm{EUR}}{\mathrm{CHF}}\cdot A$ seems fairly linear to me.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Presumably the Euro : Swiss Franc exchange rate can change over time and the $r_A$ and $r_I$ data are involves time series

Comment: To me EUR/CHF seems like a (constant) factor, which can be cancelled out.